# Mean-preserving spread, conditional probability

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, conditional-expectation, variance

Suppose real variable $Y$ is a mean-preserving spread of $X$, e.g. $Y = X + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ has expected value zero and is independent of $X$.
$X$ takes on value $r$ with positive probability. Is it then true that

$$ P(X \geq r) = P(Y \geq r)   ?$$

Comment: not for all $r$, just for those that $X$ already takes on with positive probability

Comment: I see, removed my comment. So what is the question then exactly? Is it whether or not there exists an $r$, s.t. $\mathbb P(X>r) = \mathbb P(Y>r) > 0$?

Comment: "Mean preserving spread" is known by only a handful people here. In such a case, please, give a reference such as [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean-preserving_spread)

Comment: Fair, added a definition to the question.

Comment: For Gabor, the question is, let r be a value which X takes on with positive probitlity. then does P(X > r) - P( Y > r). So for all r which X takes on with positive probability. Not does there exist an r.

Comment: @user23415, than this is actually the same question that I mentioned in my first comment. If you need this property for every such $r$ than it's the same as saying that the distribution of $X$ and the distribution of $Y$ are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is uniformly chosen from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ (you roll a die) and $\epsilon$ is uniformly chosen from $\{-100,100\}$. Then $\Pr[X \ge 6] = \frac16$ but $\Pr[X+\epsilon \ge 6] = \frac12$.

Comment: Thanks - do you have an intuition for what restriction on $\epsilon$ might make the statement true?

Comment: Well, no matter what $\epsilon$ and $X$ are, it should not be true for all values of $r$, because $X$ and $X+\epsilon$ should not have the same distribution. (Not sure if there are weird pathological counterexamples to that.) If $X, \epsilon$ are continuous and bounded, then I'm pretty sure we can find some value of $r$ that works by the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Not it is not true.

Take this for an example, where $P(X > r) \not= P(Y > r)$ for any case where $P(X=r)>0$

```
r   P(X=r) P(Y=r) P(X>r) P(Y>r)
0    0      0.1    1      0.9  
1    0.5    0.5    0.6    0.4
2    0.5    0.2    0.4    0.2
3    0      0.2    0      0
```

Comment: This is not a mean-preserving spread. I've added a definition above.

Comment: It certainly is a mean-preserving spread by any common definition.  It can even be a mean-preserving spread by your non-standard definition, for example with $P(\epsilon =-1\mid X=1)=0.2$, $P(\epsilon =0\mid X=1)=0.6$, $P(\epsilon =1\mid X=1)=0.2$, and  $P(\epsilon =-1\mid X=2)=0.4$, $P(\epsilon =0\mid X=2)=0.2$, $P(\epsilon =1\mid X=2)=0.4$, in which case $E[\epsilon]=0$.

Comment: Thanks - the question was not clear. I'm thinking of epsilon being independent of X. Do you have an intuition on whether a counterexample like this could still hold? Appreciate your effort.

Comment: It is not going to be true then either.  Take for example $X$ having the values $-1,0,1$ with equal probability and $\epsilon$ independently having the same distribution.  Then $P(X>1)=0$ but $P(X+\epsilon>1)=\frac19$.